# Group Automorphism on the smallest field containing roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $L$ be the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ that contains the solutions to $x^4-2=0$.

So $L$ will contain all the rationals.

I have in my notes $Aut(L)$ is finite, however, I cannot think of any mapping $g \in Aut(L)$ other than the identity mapping.

Since $1 \in L$ and $g$ in an automorphism, we must have that $g(1)=1$, $g(2)=2$, $\dots$. Also, roots must be mapped to roots.

Are there any other mappings in $Aut(L)$ besides the identity?

Comment: $L$ will contain the rationals, but it will also contain irrationals, for example $\sqrt[4]{2} = \sqrt{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: @fkraiem. I understand that L will also contain irrationals. I am just unsure of any other automorphism other than the identity, since $1$ is the identity element of L.

Comment: The automorphisms of $L$ are precisely the maps $\phi$ such that $\phi(x) = x$ for all $x \in \mathbf{Q}$ and if $\alpha$ is a root of $X^4-2$, $\phi(\alpha)$ is also a root of $X^4-2$. In other words, the maps which fix $\mathbf{Q}$ pointwise and send a root of $X^4-2$ to a root of $X^4-2$ (possibly the same).

Comment: And since of course $X^4-2$ has only a finite number of roots, there are finitely many such maps.

Comment: I see. I could just restrict the maps to the set of the roots.

Comment: The value of an automorphism $\phi$ at just one root $\alpha$ is sufficient to determine it at every elements of $L$, since an element of $L$ can be expressed as a linear combination of rational numbers (which you know are fixed by $\phi$) and powers of $\alpha$.

Comment: By the way, I don't think you really means "*Group* Automorphism". ;)

Comment: @fkraiem, I was trying to make my title different from those whose question was so similar to mine. However, it does sound really strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so there is an answer: for all automorphisms $\phi$ of $L$, we have

- $\phi(x) = x$ for all $x \in \mathbf{Q}$; and
- if $\alpha$ is a root of $X^4-2$, then $\phi(\alpha)$ is also a root of $X^4-2$

and conversely, if $\alpha,\beta$ are roots of $X^4-2$, there exists exactly one automorphism $\phi$ of $L$ such that $\phi(\alpha) = \beta$.

So a non-identity automorphism is given for example by $\phi(\sqrt[4]{2}) = -\sqrt[4]{2}$. This completely determines the automorphism, because if $\alpha$ is any root of $X^4-2$, any element of $L$ can be written as
$$a = a_0 + a_1\alpha + a_2\alpha^2 + a_3\alpha^3$$
where the $a_i$ are rational coefficients. Then if $\phi(\alpha) = \beta$, we have
$$\phi(a) = a_0 + a_1\beta + a_2\beta^2 + a_3\beta^3.$$